# Deserialize json string into variables

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I get this json return that I need to deserialize:

```
{
   "odata.metadata":"http://ausmtsapp01.epicorsaas.com/SaaS203/api/v1/BaqSvc/cLotInfo/$metadata#Epicor.DynamicQuery.QueryResults&$select=PartLot_PartLotDescription,PODetail_LineDesc",
   "value":[
      {
         "PartLot_PartLotDescription":"SL1900301122019",
         "PODetail_LineDesc":"Angle - Steel - A36 - Plain Finish - 3\" x 3\" x 3/8\" x 20' Lg."
      }
   ]
}
```

I have this code to deserialize the PODetail_LineDesc part into a variable and I keep getting null return. What am I doing wrong?

```
        dynamic jsonDe = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content);

        string PODetail_LineDesc = jsonDe.PODetail_LineDesc;
        frmDescription.Text = PODetail_LineDesc;
```

Comment: `jsonDe.value[0].PODetail_LineDesc`

Comment: That did it. Could you give me a why?

Comment: If I have multiple value that I need to get from the string do I keep incrementing the numbers in the [ ]?

Comment: You have a dynamic object consisting of two properties: `odata.metadata` and `value`. `Value` is an array. So to access the `PODetail_LineDesc` property you need to first access the `value` array. This is done with `value[0]` since you only got 1 element.

Comment: @Mathew: Yes exactly. As per you example there is only one element and that has the index of 0. If there are more then they will have indices 1, 2, 3 and so forth.

Comment: awesome, Thank You!

Comment: Usually getting multiple values in an array is done with a loop of some kind. `for`, `forEach`, `while` are the most common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how:

```
string PODetail_LineDesc = jsonDe.value[0].PODetail_LineDesc;
```

You have a dynamic object consisting of two properties: `odata.metadata` and `value`. `value` is an array. So to access the `PODetail_LineDesc property` you need to first access the `value` array. This is done with `value[0]` since you only got 1 element.

As per you example there is only one element and that has the index of 0. If there are more elements then they will have indices 1, 2, 3 and so forth.

Usually getting multiple values from an array is done with a loop of some kind. `for`, `foreach`, `while` are the most common.